# Boxee on Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, boxee

I have a Server 2003 box sitting on my home network doing some small menial tasks. I'm thinking of using this as an HTPC. I have never done this sort of thing before so would like to know if this would work.

Will Boxee run on Server 2003?

I plan on putting this box next to the TV and getting a VGA to TV cable and a wireless keyboard/mouse and boxee on the machine. Is there anything in this setup that will obviously not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like 2003 Server is officially supported according to their [system requirements](http://support.boxee.tv/forums/49598/entries/42689). However, that doesn't mean it won't run. The hardware components are likely to be more important that the OS. If your server is built on actual server hardware, you'll need a better graphics card. (servers tend to have low end graphic because its not all that important when its locked away in a closet somewhere).

If you're not particularly attached to 2003 server you can reformat and install any of the other supported OSs.

If you want to keep 2003 server but for some reason can't get boxee to work, there are other "media center" [applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_center#Stand-alone_software) you can try as well.